# How to compile UnifiedEmail in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I’m trying to open unifiedemail in Android Studio and compile it.

I got the bare source from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/
and imported it into Android Studio.

When I try to compile there’s a bunch of errors like this:

```
unifiedemail/res/values/styles.xml:421: error: Error retrieving parent for item:
No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
```

Adding the appcompat-v7 library jar to the AndroidStudio project does not help.

Similar questions seem to suggest to add a dependency in a gradle file, but the project does not have such a file.
Also a nearly identical version of the project is part of CyanogenMod (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_UnifiedEmail) and thus I guess it somehow compiles, but I don't know how to achieve this.